# Connect netbook to mobile internet via sim

Tags: command-line, internet

I have a HP mini 210 running ubuntu.
My netbook has a sim slot and thus I want to connect it to mobile internet.
How can I do so?

Comment: I had this machine in past and was interested about this. Can you check your network manager for "Mobile" connections? In my Kubuntu 15.04 there is position in list to create a mobile connection.

Comment: In Ubuntu (Unity desktop) should be something same.

Comment: There is no any, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your SIM card in the slot and follow the instructions given [here](http://ubuntuhak.blogspot.in/2013/08/configuring-mobile-broadband-in-ubuntu.html). In short, after you insert your SIM card, type `Network connections` in the dash and click `Add`, select `Mobile Broadband` and follow the on-screen instructions.

Also you need appropriate drivers for the slot to work. To see if there's any, go to System Settings - Software and Updates - Additional Drivers. Install the listed drivers (if any) that you can relate to WWAN.

**EDIT**: According to the output of your `lsusb`, I think the Gobi 2000 is the driver you want to use. If you can not find this from 'Additional drivers' from the above step try installing `gobi-loader` by (you need internet connection (wifior ethernet, I hope you can enable there in your laptop):

`sudo apt-get install gobi-loader`

and following instructions [here](http://csgeek-random.blogspot.in/2011/02/hp-mini-2101076nr-ubuntu-netbook-1010.html) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228960/qualcomm-gobi-wwan-modem-no-longer-appears-in-network-manager) help you.

Basically you need to extract the drivers from windows.

Comment: I did that (created new mobile broadband), but nothing happened, I mean there is no any reference to a mobile network. I wonder if there is a command that shows that the system does recognize the sim.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: vlad@vlad-HP-Mini-210-2000:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03f0:241d Hewlett-Packard Gobi 2000 Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0314 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21b4 Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: see my edited answer