# how to get a just partly appearing WWAN-dongle to work correct/permanent?

Tags: networking, kernel, modem, mobile-broadband, wwan

i have got a notebook (*HP EliteBook 8460p*) with an built in *HP hs2340 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Module* (***Ericsson F5521gw*** - the label i found on the WWAN hardware dongle)...

from the first days on the broadband module was not really working, but i didn't need it so it did not matter... from time to time (but very rare) the unchecked option "*Mobile Broadband*" appeared in the (network-manager-)panel.

i am using ubuntu precise with an 3.2 kernel, and now i updated to an lts-trusty 3.13 kernel with no changes (at this subject).

---

[this question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228960/qualcomm-gobi-wwan-modem-no-longer-appears-in-network-manager) seems to be related, but it didn't work.

the only things i found and may be related to my broadband module are the lines in `/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules`:

```
# HP hs2340 Mobile Broadband Module
ATTRS{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3a1d", ENV{ID_MM_ERICSSON_MBM}="1"
```

by the way: also `lsusb` don't lists the WWAN-dongle...

---

### UPDATE:

today the module was working without any problem, so i ran some commands to gather as much information as possible... don't know if it helps...

```
user@EliteBook_8460p ~ $ LC_ALL=C lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:3a1d Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2888 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp.
```

-

```
user@EliteBook_8460p ~ $ LC_ALL=C ifconfig
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
          inet6 addr: XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6926304 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:5186996 (5.1 MB)
```

-

```
user@EliteBook_8460p ~ $ LC_ALL=C lsusb -v -s 001:007 2>&1 >> output.log
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03f0:3a1d Hewlett-Packard 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x03f0 Hewlett-Packard
  idProduct          0x3a1d 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      3
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          371
    bNumInterfaces         11
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      8 Wireless Handset Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC WHCM:
        bcdVersion           1.00
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              6 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        1
        bSlaveInterface         2 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          2
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x07
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
          get/set/clear comm features
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x8a  EP 10 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              7 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              8 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        3
        bSlaveInterface         4 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          4
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x07
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
          get/set/clear comm features
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x89  EP 9 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              9 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        5
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      9 Device Management
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             10 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Device Management:
        bcdVersion           1.00
        wMaxCommand          2048
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x88  EP 8 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        6
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass     13 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             11 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        6
        bSlaveInterface         7 
      CDC Ethernet:
        iMacAddress                     12 (??)
        bmEthernetStatistics    0x00000000
        wMaxSegmentSize               1514
        wNumberMCFilters            0x8040
        bNumberPowerFilters              1
      UNRECOGNIZED CDC:  06 24 1a 00 01 1b
      UNRECOGNIZED CDC:  16 24 16 00 01 0d 2e 23 bb ae c1 88 11 df bc dc d9 c6 df d7 20 85
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               7
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        7
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             14 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        7
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             15 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        8
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      9 Device Management
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             16 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Device Management:
        bcdVersion           1.00
        wMaxCommand          2048
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        9
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface             17 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        9
        bSlaveInterface         10 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          10
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x07
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
          get/set/clear comm features
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber       10
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             18 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          311
    bNumInterfaces          9
    bConfigurationValue     2
    iConfiguration         19 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      8 Wireless Handset Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC WHCM:
        bcdVersion           1.00
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              6 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        1
        bSlaveInterface         2 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          2
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x07
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
          get/set/clear comm features
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x8a  EP 10 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              7 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              8 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        3
        bSlaveInterface         4 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          4
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x07
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
          get/set/clear comm features
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x89  EP 9 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              9 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        5
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      9 Device Management
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             10 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Device Management:
        bcdVersion           1.00
        wMaxCommand          2048
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x88  EP 8 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        6
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass     13 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             11 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        6
        bSlaveInterface         7 
      CDC Ethernet:
        iMacAddress                     12 (??)
        bmEthernetStatistics    0x00000000
        wMaxSegmentSize               1514
        wNumberMCFilters            0x8040
        bNumberPowerFilters              1
      UNRECOGNIZED CDC:  06 24 1a 00 01 1b
      UNRECOGNIZED CDC:  16 24 16 00 01 0d 2e 23 bb ae c1 88 11 df bc dc d9 c6 df d7 20 85
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               7
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        7
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             14 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        7
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             15 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        8
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      9 Device Management
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             16 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Device Management:
        bcdVersion           1.00
        wMaxCommand          2048
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     3
    iConfiguration         20 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface             21 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WTF...! now i've got the (damn simple) answer:**
--> i post it here and don't delete the question (although it may be a little bit embarrassing), because i searched half the the web and didn't find an answer or just a hint to the right direction!

---

Yesterday i hit the topic again, first the mobile broadband was working and after a short time no more... and some time later i noticed, it was working again after i inserted the battery in its bay! - and that was it!!!
with the battery in the bay the WWAN-dongle works like a charm, and without not.

so i finally called the HP support and asked what's the mater with the battery and the fickle WWAN-dongle (to sort out if it is a loose connection)!
they answered, it is by design that the (original) battery has to be in its bay to establish a connection to the WWAN-dongle, also if the battery is broken because of a short circuit!

i can't believe that this is really necessary, because the SIM-card is placed in a nice push-push slot (behind the battery) and the donge/antenna itself is placed at the other side of the notebook.
and additionally i'm a little bit disappointed because an all time inserted battery reduces it's lifetime...! :-/

### TL;DR:

it is a hardware related "connection"-thing... insert the battery (and leave it in the bay) and that's it.

*has somebody experience with this sort of WWAN-dongle-connections...? - is there maybe a way to get it working without having the battery energized all the time?*