# HP 840 G2 and WWAN (mobile internet)

Tags: networking

I have HP 840 G2, and sim card module (WWAN).

I placed the sim correctly to the module (below the battery).

I use ubuntu (gnome) 16.04.

However WWAN is not recognized.

Following is my lsusb.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b466 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2134 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also now that this device is coming with one of the following WWAN

```
HP lt4112 LTE/HSPA+ Qualcomm® Gobi™ 4G Module
HP lt4211 LTE/EV-DO/HSPA+ Qualcomm® Gobi™ 4G Module**
HP hs3110 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Module
```

But I do not know which one.

Is is possible to install mobile internet on my laptop and ubunt.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: i'm not sure if it the same thing, but maybe have a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/773720/354350

Comment: Thank you for answer, but unfortunately this is not related to my problem.  I am not able to see wwan.

Answer (score 2):

Your lsusb output suggests that the WWAN is not even being recognized at the bus level, as none of the entries in the list looks like a WWAN adapter.

If you have a hs3110, you should be seeing the following line in `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 03f0:521d Hewlett-Packard
```

Bus and device IDs may vary but the ID should match.

For the hs4112 the ID should be `03f0:581d`. I don’t have the ID of the hs4211 at hand, unfortunately.

If you remove the bottom cover of your laptop, you should see which device you have.

Another thing to try: on boot, hit ESC repeatedly to get the boot menu. Enter BIOS setup and open System information. This will give you a detailed overview of all components installed in your system, and the WWAN module should show up there. If it doesn’t, the module is either shot or not plugged in correctly.